# How to set the opacity of a mesh?

Tags: graphics3d, properties

I try to set the opacity of a mesh in this way:

```
bunny = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}];
Show[bunny, Opacity -> 0.5]
```

However, the mesh is fully opaque.

Is there a way to set the opacity of a mesh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either

```
Insert[bunny, Opacity[0.5], {1, 1}]
```

or

```
bunny /. Graphics3D[g_, opts___] :> Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], g}, opts]
```

will produce this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or even

```
bunny /. GraphicsComplex[x_, g_, o___] :> GraphicsComplex[x, {Opacity[0.5], g}, o]
```

Comment: Thank you. Since Mathematica does not provide a function to get the mesh vertices, I get it by `vertices = bunny[[1, 2, 1]]`. Your method is good, but it will change the position of vertices in Graphics3D (I need to modify all my codes to `vertices = bunny[[1, 3, 1]]`). Do you have any ideas about how to make it consistent?

Comment: @Purboo, See update.  Alternatively, you can get the coordinates with `coordinates = First@Cases[newbunny, GraphicsComplex[x_, __] :> x, Infinity]`.  In fact you can just use the old `bunny` and your old method -- why do you need a new way?

Comment: You can also use `MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeGraphics[newbunny]`, but it's a bit slow (I assume because of the checking that `DiscretizeGraphics` does).

Comment: Aha, I got it: `First@Cases[newbunny, GraphicsComplex[x_, __] :> x, Infinity]`. Thanks!

Comment: @Purboo, if you have to extract components, have a look at the result of `ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}, "Properties"]` to see what parts you can extract.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I can extract vertices in this way, but I have a lot of meshes which are not in the ExampleData set. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Purboo, can you give an example? Note that if you are `Import[]`-ing these objects, there are also mechanisms in place to extract vertices, polygons, etc. componentwise. Have a look at the docs for more details.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. For example, given two meshes with the same number of vertices and same connectivity, generate an interpolation from them. `mesh1 = Import["mesh1.ply"]; mesh2 = Import["mesh2.ply"]; newPts = 0.3 getVertices@mesh1 + 0.7 getVertices@mesh2; interpolation = mesh1 /. GraphicsComplex[x_, opts___] :> GraphicsComplex[newPts, opts]`

Comment: @MichaelE2, is it possible to define an impure function to set the opacity of an mesh? I may need to set the opacity several times.

Comment: @Purboo, as I told you, look up the docs for `Import[]`; in particular, the specific docs for the *.ply format. You can easily import the polygons and vertices separately. As for resetting opacity, you merely need to modify Michael's last replacement rule: `result /. o_Opacity :> Opacity[0.6]` (or some other suitable value; you get the idea). If you want colors, note that most of the coloring directives take an alpha channel.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis., experience learned; level up :)